# Calculate at runtime vs Lookup from SQL Server Table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, performance, t-sql, database-design

I have an MVC application that needs to run several tillion calculations. Of those, I am interested in only about 8 million results. I have to do this work because I need to see an overall high and low score. I will save this data, and store it is in a single table of 16 floats. I have a few indexes too on this table for lookups. So far I have only processed 5% of my data.

As users enter data into my website, I have to do calculations based on their data. I have to determine the Best and Worst outcomes. This is only about 4 million calculations. Right now, that takes about a second or less to calculate on my local PC. Or it is a simple query that will always return 2 records from my stored data. The Best and The Worst. Right now, the query to get the results is the same speed or faster than calculating the result, but I don't have all 8 million records yet. I am worried that the DB will get slow.

I was thinking I would use the Database Lookup, and if performance became an issue, switch to runtime calculation.

QUESTION: Should I just save myself the trouble and do the runtime calculation anyway?
I am not sure which option is more scalable. I don't expect a large user base for this website.
The site needs to be snappy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague to provide a clear cut answer, but my guess is using the db to calculate the totals will be far more efficient than you writing the code on the website.  Sql Server will attempt to optimize the query to use as much of the server resources as possible to make it more efficient.  Your code won't do that unless you specifically write it to do so.

I would start by loading the data and doing tests before making an optimization strategy. You have no idea where the real bottlenecks of the system will be before you load data that is remotely close to what you are going to have to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. And I am sorry I cannot give more details. Nature of the work. I agree with you. Just need a few others to confirm what I am thinking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question performing the calculation is more scalable has it is on that single data set.  As you add data to a table even with indexes lookups will get slower.   Also the indexes increase table size and increase the time required to insert a record.

Comment: The 8 million records that I initially populate the table with will be the only records in the table. No need to add any more. So, insert speed is not an issue. I just need to use this data set for looking up best and worst case at runtime.

Comment: No enough information to really comment.   Test with real data is the only real answer.  Lookup speed will degrade with more data the question is how much.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, this is a question about caching - should you calculate on the fly, or lookup the results in a cache?

In most web architectures, your SQL database is a brilliant cache, right up to the point where it becomes a terrible cache. Scaling your (SQL) database is notoriously tricky - introducing clustering, sharding etc. becomes a production in its own right.

My - very general - advice is to use your relational database for managing transactional data, and to use caching technology for caching. 8 million records should fit into RAM on a decent server these days - and you can add web servers far more cheaply than scaling your database.